# Dynamically load a C# .NET assembly in a C++Builder application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, .net-assembly, c++builder

I have a **C++ Windows application developped with RAD Studio** (C++Builder) XE4. It has some plugins, which are DLLs (always written with RAD Studio) that are dynamically loaded with [this technique](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20165).

Now in one of this plugins I need reflection capabilities. While it seems I cannot achieve them with C++ (reflection is needed on a third-party COM DLL that I cannot modify) I decided to rewrite this **plugin in C#** (which has powerful reflection capabilities), thus creating a **.NET assembly**.

I know I should expose the assembly via COM, but I can't (we don't want to change the way the main application loads all DLLs).

My aim is to **dynamically load the .NET assembly and invoke its functions** (for instance here we call `SetParam` function) with something like the following, like I do with the other plugins.

```
//load DLL
HINSTANCE handleDll = LoadLibraryW("C:/Path/to/the/assembly.dll");
//get reference to the function
void* ptr = GetProcAddress(handleDll, "_SetParam");
ptr_SetParam ptrFunc = reinterpret_cast<ptr_SetParam>(ptr);
//invoke function
int result = (*ptrFunc)(String("mykey").c_str(), String("myvalue").c_str());
```

where `ptr_SetParam` is defined as

```
typedef int(*ptr_SetParam)(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);
```

Is there a way?

Comment: [There are ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127825/c-sharp-unmanaged-exports) to bolt unmanaged exports onto a C# assembly.   Giesecke's tool gets used a lot.  Beware that this is almost never not a drastic mistake, it scales poorly and exceptions are exceedingly difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant's comment I found a way.

I created following Visual Studio projects.

**MyDllCore** .NET assembly project, written in C# or any other .NET language. Here I have my managed class like the following, where the real logic of the assembly is implemented.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//more usings...

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class HostDllB1
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public HostDllB1()
        {
        }

        public int SetParam(string name, string value)
        {
            Parameters[name] = value;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyDllBridge** DLL project, written in C++/CLI, with `/clr` compiler option. It is just a "bridge" project, it has a dependancy on MyDllCore project and has just one .cpp o .h file like the following, where I map the methods from the program that loads the DLL to the methods in the .NET assembly.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace MyNamespace;
//more namespaces...

#pragma once
#define __dll__
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "vcclr.h"
//more includes...

//References to the managed objects (mainly written in C#)
ref class ManagedGlobals 
{
public:
    static MyManagedClass^ m = gcnew MyManagedClass;
};

int SetParam(const wchar_t* name, const wchar_t* value) 
{
    return ManagedGlobals::m->SetParam(gcnew String(name), gcnew String(value));
}
```

Finally I have a **C++Builder program** that loads MyDllBridge.dll and uses its methods calling them like in the following.

```
//load DLL
HINSTANCE handleDll = LoadLibraryW("C:/Path/to/the/MyDllBridge.dll");
//get reference to the function
void* ptr = GetProcAddress(handleDll, "SetParam");
ptr_SetParam ptrFunc = reinterpret_cast<ptr_SetParam>(ptr);
//invoke function
int result = (*ptrFunc)(String("mykey").c_str(), String("myvalue").c_str());
```