# How to create a mixed dll in C++builder?

Tags: c++builder

I would like to know if anyone has tried loading a C# (or other managed DLL) into a C++ DLL (C++/CLI) in RAD Studio 10+? Any links to related posts are appreciated.

We used to do interop via COM, but for some reason, an MS bug that they are unwilling to fix anytime soon, is forcing us to look for other options.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Please clarify

Comment: @RemyLebeau So I have a C# dll. We want to use the functionality in C++. We are using COM now but no longer feasible. I see that mixed dlls are the way to do it, but the examples I see use VSC++ dlls. I am wondering if it can be done in C++Builder. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503650/dynamically-load-a-c-sharp-net-assembly-in-a-cbuilder-application?rq=2

Comment: There is no such thing as a "mixed dll". You are describing a C++ DLL that internally calls into a C# DLL. That's no different than a C++ app calling into a C# DLL. So what the other question describes should work the same in your situation, too. You need to explain what you are having trouble with to implement it in your case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, for simplicity you can drop those. Can a C++builder app load a C# dll? Other than COM interop, what other solutions are there?

Comment: Yes, if (as the other question described) the C# DLL contains [unmanaged exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127825/c-sharp-unmanaged-exports) that are compatible with C, then a simple `LoadLibrary`+`GetProcAddress()` should work just fine. Otherwise, you will have to stick with using COM interop, or hosting the .NET runtime in your C++ app, or use a 3rd party framework such as CrossTalk or Mono that can load .NET assemblies in unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18030748/2521214 however implib.exe is for 32bit DLLs those 64bit are done IIRC with mkexp.exe (but probably with different switches just try mkexp -h or /?) have not try it yet as I am stuck with 32bit for now... both utilities are in RADs bin folder ...