# Import C++/CLI dll into C++ win32 console (unmanage)

Tags: c++, .net, dll, com, activex

I have a **Managed** `C++`(`CLI-code`) that I want to use in "unmanaged" `c++` `win32`.
I know I would use technologies such as **DLL**, **COM** or **ActiveX** for using the managed code in the "unmanaged" environment.
Please someone tell me is it possible at all by any means. If yes, then how? Any examples are appreciated?

Comment: Try DLL. Thats what the best you can try in this situation

Comment: simple managed dll cant work properly in unmanaged code. i try that but i cant achieve success

Comment: where you faced the issue with this design? can u be specific? because I have tried the same in one of my project and it is working without any issues

Comment: please tell me how do you add dll to your console application? how it is handle methods param managed type?

Comment: C++/CLI is ideal to let managed code execute native code.  You are doing it the wrong way around, that makes it a lot less ideal.  [It isn't impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131801/17034).  Using COM is best.

Answer (score 0):

Use Managed code as **DLL** file and use [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzk20sxw.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx) to load the **DLL** file and get the function pointer. Using the function pointer you can execute the Managed code(**C++/CLI**) from unmanaged C++ code.